# Will Thread blocked in socketRead0() throw SocketException when Socket.close() is called?

Tags: java, sockets

As is said in **Java Concurrency In Practice**:

> Unfortunately, the read and write methods in InputStream and
>   OutputStream are not responsive to interruption,but closing
>   the underlying socket makes any threads blocked in read or
>   write throw a SocketException

So, my question is, assume that one `Thread` is blocked in native method `socketRead0()` in `SocketInputStream.read()` method, if related Socket is closed(by calling `close()`), will blocked thread receive a `SocketException` immediately?

Or nothing will happen until socket read timeout is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> assume that one Thread is blocked in native method `socketRead0()` in `SocketInputStream.read()` method, if related `Socket` is closed(by calling `close()`), will blocked thread receive a `SocketException` immediately?

Yes.

> OR nothing will happen until socket read timeout is reached?

It is immediate. There would be no point in waiting for the timeout.

Comment: So plz tell me if I'm right about this: when socket is closed, socketRead0() will return -1 immediately(rather than throws a IOException), and subsequent code will check and find that the socket has been closed, therefore throws a SocketException.

Comment: You're wrong. All these cases will throw a `SocketException: socket closed`, as I confirmed above, and as your book says, and as you said yourself. No -1.

Comment: Gocha, Thanks for your answer!